# Java3D 1.5.1 - How to place different textures on Box parts?

Tags: java, textures, java-3d

I am trying to place different textures on sides of a `Box`, but without any success.

Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage texture1 =  ...; // brown image
BufferedImage texture2 =  ...; // green image

Box box = new Box(1f, 1f, 1f, Box.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, new Appearance());

TextureAttributes ta = new TextureAttributes();
ta.setTextureMode(TextureAttributes.MODULATE);

Appearance app = new Appearance();
app.setTexCoordGeneration(new TexCoordGeneration(TexCoordGeneration.OBJECT_LINEAR, TexCoordGeneration.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2));
app.setTexture(new TextureLoader(texture1).getTexture());
app.setTextureAttributes(ta);
box.setAppearance(Box.TOP, app);

Appearance app2 = new Appearance();
app2.setTexCoordGeneration(new TexCoordGeneration(TexCoordGeneration.OBJECT_LINEAR, TexCoordGeneration.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2));
app2.setTexture(new TextureLoader(texture2).getTexture());
app2.setTextureAttributes(ta);
box.setAppearance(Box.RIGHT, app2);
```

Result:

[image: Generated box]

Well, it places the images on both sides, but as you can see, they are blured.

I thought it could be caused by wrong `TexCoordGeneration` applied to the appearance of sides. But I am also not sure if I create the `Box` instance with correct parameters.

How should I fix this?

Thank you very much for answers!

Comment: Java 3D 1.5.1 is obsolete, you should switch to Java 3D 1.6: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed that by generating my own `TexCoordGeneration` object with `Vector4f` objects.

Code:

```
app.setTexCoordGeneration(this.generateTexCoord(box.getShape(Box.TOP)));
```

and the method `generateTexCoord()`:

```
private TexCoordGeneration generateTexCoord(Shape3D shape) {
    BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox(shape.getBounds());
    Point3d lower = new Point3d();
    Point3d upper = new Point3d();
    bb.getLower(lower);
    bb.getUpper(upper);

    double width = upper.x - lower.x;
    double height = upper.y - lower.y;
    double deep = upper.z - lower.z;
    Vector4f planeX = new Vector4f((float)(1.0/width), 0.0f, 0.0f, (float)(-lower.x/width));
    Vector4f planeY = new Vector4f(0.0f, (float)(1.0/height), 0.0f, (float)(-lower.y/height));
    Vector4f planeZ = new Vector4f(0.0f, 0.0f, (float)(1.0/deep), (float)(-lower.z/deep));

    TexCoordGeneration tcg = new TexCoordGeneration(TexCoordGeneration.OBJECT_LINEAR, TexCoordGeneration.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2);
    if(width == 0) { // RIGHT, LEFT: YZ
        tcg.setPlaneS(planeZ);
        tcg.setPlaneT(planeY);
    } else if(height == 0) { // TOP, BOTTOM: XZ
        tcg.setPlaneS(planeX);
        tcg.setPlaneT(planeZ);
    } else { // FRONT, BACK: XY
        tcg.setPlaneS(planeX);
        tcg.setPlaneT(planeY);
    }
    return tcg;
}
```

Hope that helped someone with same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I was reading pages on the internet and with everything I finished the cube with different textures. I used images from my computer. Hope it works for everybody, it took me 3 days!

```
protected Node buildShape() {

    TextureLoader loader;
    Texture texture; 

    Box caja=new Box(1.5f,1.5f,1.5f,Box.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS,new Appearance());
    Appearance ap = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("blue.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.BACK,ap);

    Appearance ap2 = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("white.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap2.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.TOP,ap2);

    Appearance ap3 = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("red.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap3.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.BOTTOM,ap3);

    Appearance ap4 = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("green.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap4.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.LEFT,ap4);

    Appearance ap5 = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("orange.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap5.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.RIGHT,ap5);

     Appearance ap6 = new Appearance();

    loader = new TextureLoader("yellow.jpg",this);
    texture = loader.getTexture();
    ap6.setTexture(texture);
    caja.setAppearance(Box.FRONT,ap6);

    return caja;
}
```